# Promise.all() is not waiting for map function to resolve

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My Code looks as follows:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Post = require("../models/Post");
const User = require("../models/User");

router.get("/timeline/all", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.body.userId);
    const userPosts = await Post.find({ userId: currentUser._id });
    const friendPosts =  await Promise.all(
      currentUser.followings.map((friendId) => {
        return Post.find({ userId: friendId });
      })
    )
    console.log(friendPosts);
    res.status(200).json(userPosts.concat(friendPosts))
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I remove the const friendPosts and the call for the promise and just return the userPosts it works fine and I'm struggling to see how the promise is not resolving.

Comment: You need to add `async` in map callback `.map(async (friendId) => {})`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the map inner function , you should make that function to an `async` one and inside to `await` for that `Post.find` .

```
const friendPosts =  await Promise.all(
  currentUser.followings.map(async friendId => {
    return await Post.find({ userId: friendId });
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to define it as async function

Try this:

```
const friendPosts =  await Promise.all(
  currentUser.followings.map(async (friendId) => {
    const post = await Post.find({ userId: friendId });
    return post;
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map` function of `friendPosts` isn't returning promise. You should make the function async and return promise `Post`

```
const friendPosts =  await Promise.all(
    currentUser.followings.map(async (friendId) => await Post.find({ userId: friendId }))
);
```